# How to fix "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-core, rxjs

How can i fix this error. The value updates in the table but don't reflect in the UI until refresh the page.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just check the value is exist or not. If exist then do the looping or the operation you want to do.

Comment: Please don't add images of code and error! Instead, copy-paste them to your question. Additionally, make sure that you inserted the full code needed to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal Reproducible Example](/help/reprex) for more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are trying to call updateValue, the valueMap still doesn't have a defined value for the corresponding idea. Which means it's undefined at that time.

You can solve it in 2 differents ways, based on what you are looking for.

First you can make sure the value is always defined. Either by making sure it's always set beforehand, or by encapsulating the rest of the method in a condition testing if the value is undefined or not.

Or you can make sure it's always returning a default value using some kind of coalescence:

`const valCells = this.valueMap.get(id) || [];`

Answer (score 1):

You should define valCells as array.
Like this:

```
let valCells = [];
valCells = this.valueMap.get(id)
```